# How can the Jenkins pipeline fetch the test results executed inside docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a Jenkins pipeline as following

```
Checkout SCM → Build Docker Image → Test
```

Supposed I build a docker image, so-called `foo` at `Build Docker Image` stage. There are Java tests which are executed at the `Test` stage. This is done, of course, inside `foo`.

My question is

How can the Jenkins pipeline fetch or realize the test results which are executed inside `foo` at `Test` stage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multistage image with maven and jre. Maven will package and test the source code. Jre will execute your jar.

This all can be in one step or stage in Jenkins pipeline.